# question about univalent function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, 1-1 with 
$f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, where $S$ is the unit disk. 
Let $g$ be a function defined as $g(z)=\frac{f(rz)}{r}$ for some $r$ in between $0$ and $1$.
Then how do I show that $g$ maps $S$ onto the interior of a Jordan curve.
what I think is, if $f$ is bounded  with bound $p$, then the circle of radius $\frac{p}{r}$ does the work, but no idea for the case when $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: Unless my understanding is faulty, you have a problem with the statement of the result you are trying to prove. If we have $f$ satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$, then $f$ cannot be univalent in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: I corrected the condition for $f'(0)$ to the usual normalization.

Comment: Sorry that was 1 only instead of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the correction $f'(0)=1$ instead of the nonsensical $f'(0)=0$. In fact, the analyticity of $f$ and normalization you use are irrelevant, it suffices to assume that $f: S\to {\mathbb C}$ is 1-1 and continuous. Since $f$ is 1-1 on the open unit disk, the function $g$ is 1-1 on closed unit disk and, hence, a homeomorphism onto its image. Thus, $g(\partial S)$ is a Jordan curve, which bounds the disk $g(S)$.